Preserve order of requests with multiple workers
I am designing a solution where a service (Spring boot) will listen to requests coming from clients.
The order of the requests needs to be preserved e.g. if client 1 updates the address of customer A to X and client 2 updates the address of customer A to Y, the address needs to be Y.
Since the Tomcat server in a Spring boot application is multi-threaded I was thinking to introduce a queue on which the requests / commands are being put with a timestamp (= the moment they are received).
The only problem that I see is that if I put everything on a queue, I can only have one consumer / worker to preserve the order. This also means if the first request / command is being blocked, e.g. network outage all subsequent requests / command are also blocked.
So I would like to introduce some parallelism where multiple workers consume the queue, albeit the order is being preserved. I assume this can be done by partitioning by customer id and then have a consumer group per partition.
Does this seem as the best solution or do you know of other patterns to implement this ?

Just to be clear, You are saying that requests pertaining to the same customer id must be fulfilled in the same order in which they arrived, but requests pertaining to different customer ids may be fulfilled concurrently. Is that correct?

Also, You might mention whether some requests could involve more than one customer id, or whether there always is only one customer id per request.

One customer id per request and requests pertaining to different customer ids may be fullfilled concurrently.

A naïve approach would be to have one queue for each worker thread, and use a hash of the customer id to choose the queue for each incoming request. A more sophisticated approach could be needed if just a few customer ids appeared much more frequently than others, and two or more of them happened to hash to the same queue.
